# wicked_pdf header not working on windows but the footer does

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

The `header`, `footer` renders just fine on my `Mac` and `Linux`, but when using the same codebase on `windows` the `header` does not render on the `pdf`.

I am wondering what could be the reason. And how to debug this issue. The `header` just siliently disappear.

If I exchange header for footer, the same content does appear in the footer.

This is how the render code looks -

```
render pdf: "#{@report.patient.name} - #{@report.created_at.strftime("%d %b %y")}",
       show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
       page_size: 'A4',
       layout: 'pdf.html.haml',
       margin: { bottom: 20, top: 65 },
       header: { spacing: 63, html: { template: 'shared/pdf/header.pdf.haml', layout: 'layouts/header.pdf.haml' } },
       footer: { html: { template: 'shared/pdf/footer.pdf.haml', layout: 'layouts/footer.pdf.haml' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists with current version of `wkhtmltopdf`. Installing an older version [from here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/old-downloads.html) fixed the issue.